# X-Editable Select2 with key and value

Tags: x-editable

In X-Editable using select2 tags, why can't we give key and value to select multiple values. is there any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $('#username').editable({
    source: [ {value: 1, text: 'Male'},
        {value: 2, text: 'Female'}],
    select2: {
        multiple: true,  // for multiple select 2 values
    },
    pk: 1, // primary key
    url: 'post.aspx',
    name: 'username'
   });
```

Comment: Please add some comments about your solution on why and how it solves the problem

Comment: use this file as a reference for all your use cases https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/assets/demo.js
Above mentioned javascript is a file behind x-editable demo
https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/demo-bs3.html?c=inline#